# How to install nvidia-driver-520-open driver flavor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

A couple of days ago [NVIDIA drivers team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) released the 520 "open" driver version.

I tried to install it, but seems that kernel modules do not load properly, and thus the gpu driver itself and I end up with a downsized resolution when GNOME boots. I noticed an error `ERROR [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to register device` after grub boot screen, which disappears if I set `iommu=off` as [suggested here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-440-82-failed-to-register-device/122520) in the [kernel boot parameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters), and I [get more information in that screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56AsY.jpg), which doesn't show any indication of an error, but I still end up with the same kind of problem.

The same issue is not present if I install the non-"open" ppa driver distribution.

I am setting iommu=off parameter incorrectly? The way I did it was as suggested in the ubuntu wiki page linked above.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Good chance a just released driver is not going to work. Personally I would never try a new driver till its been around for at least a few weeks.

Comment: https://www.phoronix.com/news/NVIDIA-520.61.05-Linux It appears as the drivers are for the H100 cards but not yet released for or fixed for consumer GPUs.  Even the nvidia-driver-515-open fails on my system trying to grab the exact video card.  If you don't have the H100 card (or looks like RTX 40 series) then the driver is not for you.

Comment: @Terrance ah makes sense, I have a 30xx series card